# BestMatchAdapter confuse two different questions with same response

Tags: python, chatterbot

Using the BestMatchAdapter of Chatterbot, it confuses two questions with the same answer. For example, training the ai.yml.

> What is ai?
>
> Artificial Intelligence is the branch of engineering and science devoted to constructing machines that think.
>
> What is a joke?
>
> Artificial Intelligence is the branch of engineering and science devoted to constructing machines that think.

On the otherhand, the following similar questions make much sense in the bot answer:

> Can you bend?
>
> No I can be perpetuated indefinitely.
>
> Can you lie?
>
> No I can be perpetuated indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

@taiwotman I don't know the corpus files you have trained. In short the best match algorithm works like this, Bot will iterate all the statements which you have trained the bot.

```
closest_match.confidence = 0

# Find the closest matching known statement
for statement in statement_list:
    confidence = self.compare_statements(input_statement, statement)

    if confidence > closest_match.confidence:
        statement.confidence = confidence
        closest_match = statement
```

Chatterbot uses the default statement comparison algorithm is [levenshtein_distance](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/blob/master/chatterbot/comparisons.py#L35)

In your example, the scenario look like this

```
confidence = self.compare_statements('What is ai?',  'what is ai')
```

In this the **confidence is 1.0** and you will get answer `Artificial Intelligence is the branch of engineering and science devoted to constructing machines that think.`

I think you were confused with this case. The chatterbot `default threshold values is 65%`. Among on all statement which have **greater confidence** then it will become as response.

```
confidence = self.compare_statements('What is ai?',  'What is a joke?')
```

In this the **confidence is 0.77 which is greater than 0.65** and you will get answer `Artificial Intelligence is the branch of engineering and science devoted to constructing machines that think.` I think you tried your bot `ai conversations` other you may get accurate results.

However you could get more granular results by setting confidence to **0.90** by using [low-confidence-response-adapter](http://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/logic/index.html#low-confidence-response-adapter).

The same answer applies to second question also. Let me know your suggestion/improvements on this question

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. I did the training with the ai.yml file. Please permit me to study this algorithm and get back within 48hrs. What you are talking about is the weight computation vis-a-vis the [levenshtein_distance](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/blob/master/chatterbot/comparisons.py#L35).

Comment: `CHATTERBOT = {
    'name': 'Tech Support Bot',
    'logic_adapters': [
         {
            "import_path": "chatterbot.logic.BestMatch",
            "statement_comparison_function": "chatterbot.comparisons.levenshtein_distance",
            "response_selection_method": "chatterbot.response_selection.get_first_response"
         },

            {
                'import_path': 'chatterbot.logic.LowConfidenceAdapter',
                'threshold': 0.90,
                'default_response': 'I am sorry, but I do not understand.'
            },
         
   
    ], `

Answer (score 1):

This adjustment makes it work @Mallikarjunarao Kosuri(much credit for your suggestion).

```
CHATTERBOT = {
        'name': 'Tech Support Bot',
        'logic_adapters': [
             {
                "import_path": "chatterbot.logic.BestMatch",
                "statement_comparison_function": "chatterbot.comparisons.levenshtein_distance",
                "response_selection_method": "chatterbot.response_selection.get_first_response"
             },

                {
                    'import_path': 'chatterbot.logic.LowConfidenceAdapter',
                    'threshold': 0.90,
                    'default_response': 'I am sorry, but I do not understand.'
                },

        ],
```