# Empty Chatterbot Conversation table in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, chatterbot

In Django admin, the chatterbot conversion table is empty after training has been performed using

`python manage.py train`

The above code populates the statement and response tables with the training data based on the yml file. This is fine.

However, during testing, the statements posted to the chatbot and the response ought to go to the empty conversation table and should not be added to the trained statement and response data table.

Answer (score 2):

When you start the conversation interface then bot will start recording all your conversations into DB.

If you look into [source code](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/blob/1071136e922f12c9a6ba12ac24e0fadf98024a84/chatterbot/ext/django_chatterbot/views.py#L38) of chatterbot, if conversations are exists in DB then the conversation will append into existing conversation, else it will create a new identifier

```
    conversation.id = request.session.get('conversation_id', 0)
    existing_conversation = False
    try:
        Conversation.objects.get(id=conversation.id)
        existing_conversation = True

    except Conversation.DoesNotExist:
        conversation_id = self.chatterbot.storage.create_conversation()
        request.session['conversation_id'] = conversation_id
        conversation.id = conversation_id

    if existing_conversation:
        responses = Response.objects.filter(
            conversations__id=conversation.id
        )

        for response in responses:
            conversation.statements.append(response.statement.serialize())
            conversation.statements.append(response.response.serialize())

    return conversation
```

A sample Django chatterbot ADMIN page of conversations

[image]

Let me know if you need any further help on this.

Comment: Great!  Thanks for making the clarification.  The only other help I need is w.r.t. to another of my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45910997/bestmatchadapter-confuse-two-different-questions-with-same-response). Kindly, let me know your opinion on it. Thanks again.

Comment: sure i will do ASAP

Comment: Thanks. Still, I feel that there is duplication going on and I hope future chatterbot release would correct this. The conversation table should only contain the user's statement that is posted and the response. The Statement and Response table ought to have only the training data as populated using `python manage train` and nothing else from the user's input.

Comment: Correct, I think could you report an GitHub issue with your observations so that tracking issues will be easier.

Comment: I have some more comments here https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/issues/957#issuecomment-325902300

Comment: how we should training module in initial phase. if i use this `trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatbot)

    #Train the chatbot based on the english corpus
    trainer.train("chatterbot.corpus.english")`
in views. it creates different table.